# IllegalArgumentException + continue to avoid breaking program?

Tags: java, break, illegalargumentexception, continue

I want to ask if it is possible to stop a  IllegalArgumentException from breaking the program running. If I do:

```
throw new 
IllegalArgumentException("Value not 
allowed!");
continue;
```

Will this stop the IAE from breaking the program after the exception is triggered? If not, is there any way to just throw this as an error message to the user and then allow them to continue running the program without having to re-run?

Comment: Just print a message then: `System.err.println("Value not allowed!");`

Comment: The point of throwing an exception is to crash the program if the thrown error isn't handled. If you don't want the program to crash as a result of the error, you likely shouldn't be throwing an exception, or you should be catching it somewhere else up the call chain.

Comment: Read about try-catch block.

Comment: `throw` _means_ "stop and move back up the call stack now".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you want to handle an exception (i.e. stop the program from terminating), you must use a [try/catch](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp) block.
2. Whenever an exception is thrown, control exits immediately.  Your "continue" statement is *NOT* executed.
3. When you "catch" an exception, you may re-throw it.  You'll presumably have another try/catch block at some higher level in the code.
4. Your *BEST* strategy, however, is to "code defensively" and try to prevent the IllegalArgumentException from occurring in the first place.
5. Finally, you *NEVER* want to *LOSE* information.

   ```
   /*
    * Poor: 
    * *WHAT* value???  Where did this occur?  Why?
    * You've just lost all this information, "Value not allowed" is uselessly vague...
    */
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value not allowed!");
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'll use try/catch instead. As for the "value", this is an idea from a full program I have, with other classes from which the value is received, I just didn't want to overcomplicate a simple question/idea I got more out of curiosity. The value makes sense in the context of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `try..catch` structure to "intercept" the exception or just don't throw exception in the first place.